# Изменить цвет иконы в TITLE при изменениях на сайте

Tags: предложение

Господа, есть такая идея, нельзя ли сделать так, что бы цвет иконы в title изменялся при активности.  Когда работаешь, часто видишь, что после иконы появляется цифра, когда на сайте новые вопросы, а что если цвет иконки будет меняться, если изменения касаются лично тебя? Например, когда кто-то прокомментировал ответ или прокомментировал вопрос или есть комментарии новые в вопросе в котором участвуешь или есть ответ к твоему вопросу... Я по своему небольшому опыту скажу, что когда работаю и у меня открыта вкладка SO я могу и не заглянуть и не вспомнить, если голова забита работой...  Мне кажется, что это была-бы удобной опцией на сайте...  Цвета уже определены, это красный и зеленый, не думаю, что целесообразно делать двух цветов, что бы икона была бы красной при комментарии или зеленой при начисленных  балах, можно выбрать один цвет, главное, чтобы видно было, что есть изменения...
Ну если не цвет иконы менялся, а то можно сделать просто точку на пару пикселей красным возле иконы...  Думаю идею вы поняли...

[image: Наподобии]

Comment: Не сделают, т. к. тут стараются персонализацию страниц не делать. Даже фильтрация скрытия сделана на клиенте вместо сервера :(

Comment: Жаль, но это было-бы удобно...

Comment: Могу посоветовать просто поставить какое-либо расширение для браузера. Например https://stackapps.com/questions/6455/stack-exchange-notifications-inbox-achievements-score-improve-text-editor-an

Comment: Спасибо за совет, Алексей, я даже не знал, что есть такое... Поставил, но я не большой любитель суррогата, люблю когда все натуральное и свое)))

Comment: Иконы какие-то ... Я без картинки вообще мало что понял. Может добавите? С красными рукописными кругами конечно же.

Comment: alexolut, а что именно не понятно?

Comment: Добавил наглядный пример

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, после добавления предложенного тобой расширения, если честно не работает, в настройках все включил, а когда были изменения на сайте, например мне тут коммент написали, а уведомление не сработало...

Comment: P.S. Для уведомления в комментариях надо добавлять символ собаки @ перед именем, иначе оповещения не будет.

Comment: alexolut, я добавляю. просто когда добавляю, у меня выскакивает только  имя  Алексей Шиманский

Comment: Потому что у него ник русскими буквами, начните писать латинскую “a” (первая буква имени участника) после собаки, и увидите. P.S. Я всё еще не получаю уведомлений.

Comment: @alexolut, благодарю, щас увидел, если честно не знал об этом...  щас уверен уведомление будет